# Google Storyboard Features

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

I have questions about Google storytelling services
Isn't it possible to exchange information between user and story?
Unable to insert likes on story slides?
Can't comment on slides?
And is it possible to poll users?

Answer (score 0):

Quizzes and polls are currently under development for the AMP stories format: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/25615